# No option to archive Outlook on Windows 7 with Outlook 2010

Tags: windows, outlook, archive

I currently have a user who desperately needs to archive his email and there is no option on his Outlook currently to do so.

Comment: Well its certainly available in outlook 2010 - I remember turning it off via GPO so my users wouldn't archive their email outside of our controlled system.

Comment: Dear those that have voted to close this question, why are you voting to migrate this to superuser? Serverfault is the correct site for this question. The question might not offer much in the way of detail, but `I currently have a user` clearly indicates that the question is not off topic, and is on the correct site.

Answer (score 0):

File Tab -> Options -> Advanced -> AutoArchive

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to Right click the Inbox -> Properties -> AutoArchive tab.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following technet article.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-customize/archive-option-missing-from-outlook-since-latest/4a897efd-4cc3-4821-855a-f19ef77d6591

I had quite a few machines last year that got the bad update from M$ that nuked the archive feature. The 'repaired' it, however it overwrote the already installed update. In a few circumstances, I had to remove all the updates pertaining to the 'fix' before running windows update again.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the auto-archive to a PST or the Exchange Server Personal Archive in Exchange 2010? If you are looking to use the personal archive in Exchange 2010, you need at least Outlook Professional to see the archive folder.